# Alter Table Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Solved**

I've read so many topics about this issue and still no luck, any idea why this doesn't work? This DDL was generated by Symfony/Doctrine.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
CREATE TABLE parent_table (first_id INT NOT NULL, second_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(first_id, second_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE child_table (first_id INT NOT NULL, second_id INT NOT NULL, third_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_125B5ABCD871DC26E524616D (second_id, first_id), PRIMARY KEY(first_id, second_id, third_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE child_table ADD CONSTRAINT FK_125B5ABCD871DC26E524616D FOREIGN KEY (second_id, first_id) REFERENCES parent_table (second_id, first_id);
```

> LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR 2014-04-30 12:41:26 f3c Error in foreign key
>
> constraint of table test/#sql-4b8_37:
>   FOREIGN KEY (second_id,
>   first_id) REFERENCES parent_table (second_id, first_id):
>
> Cannot find
>   an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear
>   as the first columns, or column types in the table and the referenced
>   table do not match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type
>   of ENUM and SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and
>   such columns in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new
>   tables. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

Comment: Curiosity: why are your Foreign Key columns used in reverse (second, first)?

Comment: Don't want to believe it but that was the case.. thanks! It seems that Doctrine has switched columns order for some reason.